# hibernate 5.6.14 logback logging is working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logback

I have a Spring application (not spring boot!!!) with Hibernate. The Spring framework version is 5.3.26. Hibernate version is 5.6.14.Final

```
<!-- Logging dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Practically i want to log application related classes as DEBUG + all other classes (spring, flyway, poi, etc) to one file, and SQL related classes to another file. This is logback.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <configuration debug="true">
      <property name="LOGS" value="${APP_HOME}/logs" />
      <appender name="RollingFileAll"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/all.log</file>
    <encoder
      class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/all-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
      </fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>250MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  
  <appender name="RollingFileSql"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/sql.log</file>
    <encoder
      class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %p %c{3} [%t] user=%X{userName} %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/sql-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
      </fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>250MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <!-- LOG "application classes" at debug level -->
  <logger name="com.Application.cctng" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAll" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSql"  />
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSql"  />
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSql"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSql"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileSql"/>
  </logger>

  <!--   LOG everything at INFO level-->
  <root level="info" >
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAll" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

But the sql log file is completely empty, while the application related log is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss logging tries to find the proper logging provider.

- First, it checks a system property `org.jboss.logging.provider`. I didn't have that - of course.
- Then, tries based on classes available in the classpath. For some reason log4j2 is prioritized over slf4j. And in my case I use Apache POI, which contains log4j2 classes, therefore the system found the classes, and log4j2 logging framework is selected as logging provider. However I didn't have log4j2 configuration in Resources, so, no hibernate log.

That means, the solution for me is to setup `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider="slf4j"` as a JVM options.